# MySQL Group By Year Results are changing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL statement that selects a range of values and then groups them by year/month/day. This appears to work fine.

What is really confusing, is that if I run this SQL on the next day, the result numbers change. I think overall, the numbers are correct, but they change by one or two when run on different days.

eg.

```
select Date_format(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d") as Date, count(*) as Online 
from 
`promotion` p, `subscription` s 
where 
p.`uid` = s.`uid` and 
s.`productId` = "groupproduct"
startDate < now() 
GROUP BY YEAR(startDate), MONTH(startDate), DAYOFMONTH(startDate);
```

**Results on Day X**

```
2012-12-25  265
2012-12-26  264
2012-12-27  232
2012-12-28  187
2012-12-29  171
2012-12-30  8935
2012-12-31  3117
```

**Results on Day X+1**

```
2012-12-25  265
2012-12-26  264
2012-12-27  231
2012-12-28  187
2012-12-29  171
2012-12-30  8933
2012-12-31  3114
```

Notice how on 27.12.2012 and 30.12.2012 the result are off by one. What am I missing? I assume there is a counting error using the Group by functions, but I don't know what.

NB.
This SQL is run by a cronjob each day in the morning. Not by hand, so I don't think user error is to blame here (except in the creation of the statement).

EDIT:
Sorry, there was a mistake in the printed SQL (I changed it slightly for the public). It should be startDate every where. The issue still stands.

Comment: Perhaps the startdate for one of the historic entries has the wrong year!?!?

Comment: Why not provid us with you tables and sample data for it. :) If you are using start date then group by it, or else group by product date.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you group by `startDate` but output `purchaseDate` `(Date_format(purchaseDate, "%Y-%m-%d"))`. What `PurchaseDate` will MySQL select for each group?

I think your SQL should looks like:

```
select Date_format(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d") as Date, count(*) as Online 
from 
`promotion` p, `subscription` s 
where 
p.`uid` = s.`uid` and 
s.`productId` = "groupproduct"
startDate < now() 
GROUP BY Date_format(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d");
```

or if you need `purchaseDate`

```
select Date_format(purchaseDate, "%Y-%m-%d") as Date, count(*) as Online 
from 
`promotion` p, `subscription` s 
where 
p.`uid` = s.`uid` and 
s.`productId` = "groupproduct"
startDate < now() 
GROUP BY Date_format(purchaseDate, "%Y-%m-%d");
```

Comment: And I will try the first example you have, using GROUP BY Date_format(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First, is it really possible to have a record with `startDate >= now()`? This shouldn't cause the problem you're having, but I just don't see the need for it.  Second, your `GROUP BY` clause is grouping down to each unique day, so why aren't you simply using `GROUP BY DATE(startDate)`?

These two suggestions would reduce your query to

```
select Date_format(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d") as Date, count(*) as Online 
from 
`promotion` p, `subscription` s 
where 
p.`uid` = s.`uid` and 
s.`productId` = "groupproduct"
GROUP BY DATE(startDate);
```

These changes improve your query but the results of neither this version nor your original should vary on a day-to-day basis. All the results which have changed show fewer records, so I would guess that users are deleting records.